# Is NetworkByteOrder is the same as Big endian?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I create a demo to prove network byte order is the same as big endian:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include "winsock2.h"
#define BL32(x)  ((((x) & 0x000000ffUL) << 24) | \
                 (((x) & 0x0000ff00UL) <<  8) | \
                 (((x) & 0x00ff0000UL) >>  8) | \
                 (((x) & 0xff000000UL) >> 24))
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    uint32_t s = INT_MAX; // little endian
    uint32_t network = htonl(s);
    uint32_t bigendian = BL32(s);
    if(network == bigendian) {
        printf("nbo is same as big endian\n");
    } else {
        printf("nbo isn't same as big endian\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program runs on an x86(litte endian) Windows PC, and it gives output:

```
nbo is same as big endian
```

I didn't see this mentioned in the textbook or tutorial, so I want to confirm it's right or not.

BTW I think it's very important to help understand what is byte order in the network. Why most of the question concentrates only on "big vs little endian"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can read it in the Wikipedia article on [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

> Big-endian is the most common format in data networking; fields in the protocols of the Internet protocol suite, such as IPv4, IPv6, TCP, and UDP, are transmitted in big-endian order. For this reason, big-endian byte order is also referred to as **network byte order**.

You generally don't need to know whether network byte order is big- or little-endian. Just use the `ntohX` and `htonX` macros, and it will do the right thing. If you're on hardware that has the same byte order as the network protocols, it will leave the value alone; if you're on a machine with the opposite byte order, it will swap the bytes.